# How to bring a subview's subview to top?

Tags: ios, swift

The following print screen shows my layout:

[image]

I have the main view , then a Top view and then a picture.

When I press on the picture, I want a semi transaprent black screen appearing on the entire view:

```
        let scrennRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let coverView = UIView(frame: scrennRect)
        coverView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3)
        self.view.addSubview(coverView)
```

But I want my picture to stay on top of the coverView ?
Is there a way I can bring only the picture to be in front of the coverView ?

Comment: Yeah, but imageView its inside Top view not self.view, thats my problem.

Comment: It doesn't work because I have this: mainView -> coverView -> Topview -> imageView....top view needs to bring imageview to top, and then somehow cover view.

Comment: try this sample: https://github.com/adrianstanciu24/coverView-test/blob/master/testuiimageview/ViewController.swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your coverView and imageView have different super views.

That's why you cannot bring the imageView to the front.

In order to bring the imageView to the front you need to move it outside of the Top View so your View contains the Top view and the imageView.
Then, you can add the coverView to the main view, and bring the imageView to the front.

Another solution:
Place an image view inside the coverView at the exact same position.

Comment: Yes, that it's my problem, but moving the picture inside another view, doesn't really work for me, because of the auto layout and the constraints set to the superview.

Comment: Well then just put another image view inside the coverView and set the trailing leading top and bottom constraints to the image view. You can do this easily in the interface builder and set the alpha value of the coverView to 0 and then set it to 1 in code.

Answer (score 0):

This should do your work. Any view maintains a stack of its subviews.

```
self.view.addSubView(blackTransparentView);
self.view.bringSubViewToFront(myImageView);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. self.view does not contains imageView directly.

Comment: Whichever you want to top, bring it in the front in last.